BackBlaze B2 Cloud Storage: b2_upload_file endpoint endlessly hangs
I have a NextJS application that is using Backblaze B2 Cloud Storage to store videos and photos that a user wishes to upload.
I seem to be having an odd issue when trying to upload files. Basically, I seem to have no issues when attempting to upload photos, it always succeeds. The problem seems to start when attempting to upload videos. I've tried uploading small videos (1mb, 2mb) and it succeeds however the moment I attempt to upload any video that is above 2mb, the request just hangs endlessly without throwing any errors making it hard to determine where the problem could be.
This issue is also demonstrating some inconsistency since I was once able to successfully store a 4mb video however this only happened once, my other attempts lead to an endless hang with no errors being thrown.
I am using the 'backblaze-b2' library in my project: https://github.com/yakovkhalinsky/backblaze-b2
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the method that is being called by a Next component (located within a class):
**please do not mind the console.logs
static async uploadContent(file: File, storeContentInfo: Function) {
        try {
            const arrayBuffer = await new Promise<ArrayBuffer>((resolve, reject) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
                reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as ArrayBuffer);
                reader.onerror = reject;
            });

            const base64String = Buffer.from(arrayBuffer).toString('base64');

            if (!base64String) {
                throw new Error('Failed to read file content');
            }

            const contentId = BackBlazeHelpers.generateUniqueId();
            const contentInfo = {
                fileName: file.name,
                fileType: file.type,
                fileContent: base64String,
                contentId,
                contentInfo: {
                    size: file.size,
                },
            };

            console.log('CLIENT SIDE: RIGHT BEFORE API CALL');

            // STORE FILE IN BACKBLAZE
            const response = await axiosInstance.post('/api/upload-content', contentInfo);

            // STORE FILE INFO IN FIREBASE
            storeContentInfo(contentId, response.data.fileUrl, file.type, file.size);

            console.log('Upload successful', response.data.fileUrl);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error uploading content', error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    }

Here is the method that is located inside of my api folder which is responsible for communicating with the Backblaze API:
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '50mb',
        },
    },
};

const uploadContent = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(405).end();
    }

    const { fileName, fileType, fileContent, contentId, contentInf } = req.body;


    try {
        const b2 = new B2({
            applicationKey: B2_APPLICATION_KEY,
            applicationKeyId: B2_KEY_ID,
        });

        // GET AUTHORIZATION
        await b2.authorize();

        // GET UPLOAD URL
        const uploadUrlResponse = await b2.getUploadUrl({
            bucketId: BUCKET_ID,
        });

        const { uploadUrl, authorizationToken } = uploadUrlResponse.data;

        // UPLOAD THE FILE
        await b2.uploadFile({
            uploadUrl,
            uploadAuthToken: authorizationToken,
            fileName: encodeURIComponent(fileName),
            mime: fileType,
            data: Buffer.from(fileContent, 'base64'),
            hash: 'do_not_verify',
        });

        // URL THAT LEADS TO THE FILE THAT WAS UPLOADED
        const fileUrl = `https://f003.backblazeb2.com/file/${BUCKET_NAME}/${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`;

        return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Upload successful', fileUrl });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading content' });
    }
};


Where you catch the error, you should also log the content of the response, if it is present. For example:
    ...
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        if (error.response) {
            console.error(error.response.data);
        }
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading content' });
    }

This should give you more insight into why the upload is failing.
So, what should you do in response to such a failure?
The backblaze-b2 library is a thin layer over the Backblaze B2 Native API, and does not implement any retries in case of errors. As the B2 docs on uploading single files state,

Backblaze recommends that you write your code to try five different upload URLs before you report an error. Two attempts are almost always sufficient, and five failures is a sign that something is wrong with your request or that you are having problems connecting to the Backblaze B2 service.

There are more details at that doc link; in particular, when you do retry, you need to call b2_get_upload_url to get a new URL, then call b2_upload_file using that URL.
Here's a version of your back end code that does so:
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '50mb',
        },
    },
};

const MAX_RETRIES = 5;

const uploadContent = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        return res.status(405).end();
    }

    const { fileName, fileType, fileContent, contentId, contentInf } = req.body;


    const b2 = new B2({
        applicationKey: B2_APPLICATION_KEY,
        applicationKeyId: B2_KEY_ID,
    });

    // GET AUTHORIZATION
    await b2.authorize();

    let delay_ms = 1000;
    for (let i = 0; i < MAX_RETRIES; i++) {
        try {
            // GET UPLOAD URL
            const uploadUrlResponse = await b2.getUploadUrl({
                bucketId: BUCKET_ID,
            });

            const { uploadUrl, authorizationToken } = uploadUrlResponse.data;

            // UPLOAD THE FILE
            await b2.uploadFile({
                uploadUrl,
                uploadAuthToken: authorizationToken,
                fileName: encodeURIComponent(fileName),
                mime: fileType,
                data: Buffer.from(fileContent, 'base64'),
                hash: 'do_not_verify',
            });

            // URL THAT LEADS TO THE FILE THAT WAS UPLOADED
            const fileUrl = `https://f003.backblazeb2.com/file/${BUCKET_NAME}/${encodeURIComponent(fileName)}`;

            return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Upload successful', fileUrl });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            if (error.response) {
                console.error(error.response.data);
            }
            // Don't say we're retrying if it's the last time round the loop
            if (i < (MAX_RETRIES - 1)) {
                console.error(`Waiting ${delay_ms} milliseconds before retry.`)
                // Exponential backoff to allow transient issues to resolve
                await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay_ms));
                delay_ms *= 2;                
            }
        }
    }

    console.error(`Retried ${MAX_RETRIES} times. Returning an error response.`)
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Error uploading content' });
};

Note - I haven't tested this, but it looks correct to me!
